# How do you traverse only one ply of children in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking for a way to find and traverse a tables headers to find a specific header to test against the column.  But I have tables inside the table that also have headers and I can't seem to find away avoid the child.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        Name
    </th>
    <th>
        Description
    </th>
    <th class="no-edit">
        Strings table
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Foo
    </td>
    <td>
        Everything you need to know about Foo
    </td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    text
                </th>
                <th class="no-edit">
                    language
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Foo for you
                </td>
                <td>
                    English
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Foo pour vous
                </td>
                <td>
                    French
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Bar
    </td>
    <td>
        Everything you need to know about Bar
    </td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    text
                </th>
                <th class="no-edit">
                    language
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Bar for me
                </td>
                <td>
                    English
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Bar pour moi
                </td>
                <td>
                    French
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
var isNoEdit = false;

var header = element.closest('TABLE')[0].getElementsByTagName('th');
for (var i = 0, cell; cell = header[i]; i++) 
{
    var noEdit = cell.hasClass("no-edit");
    if (noEdit)
    {
        isNoEdit = true;
    }
}
```

or

```
var isNoEdit = false;

var header = element.find('tr th');
for (var i = 0, cell; cell = header[i]; i++) 
{
    var noEdit = cell.hasClass("no-edit");
    if (noEdit)
    {
        isNoEdit = true;
    }
}
```

The header variable give me all the children that have the 'th' tag name. Even the sub tables headers. 
Any ideas of how I can limit the find to on play of children?

Comment: I don't mind the down votes.  Just please tell me what I did wrong so I can fix it.

Comment: If you want someone to give you a hand you'll need to include *all* the relevant information. That includes your DOM structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use child selectors:

```
var header = element.closest('table').find('> tr > th');
```

Remember that this type of selector derives straight from CSS. There are others available through jQuery methods, but this is probably the simplest approach.